# I want the title of my note that I clicked on to change NOT the first note of the list

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-lists, listitem

I am trying to finish building out the edit functionality of my minimal note-taking app, but the problem is that after I edit my title and click on the "save" button, the title of the first note of the list changes but I want the title of the note that I clicked on to change.

Here is my js code:

```js
// display list of notes on the side
    
      const noteContainer = document.querySelector(".column is-one-quarter")
      const noteList = document.querySelector(".menu-list")
    
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(note) {
        note.forEach(function(note) {
          noteList.innerHTML += `<li><a id="note" data-id=${note.id} class="menu-item">${note.title}</a></li>`
        })
      })
    
      // display details of each note

      const noteDetail = document.querySelector(".note-detail")
    
      noteList.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (event.target.className === "menu-item") {
          fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes/${event.target.dataset.id}`)
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
          })
          .then(function(note) {
              noteDetail.innerHTML = `<h1 contenteditable="true" id="title" data-id=${note.id} class="subtitle is-2">${note.title}</h1><p contenteditable="true" id="body" data-id=${note.id} class="subtitle is-6">${note.body}</p><a id="save" class="button is-small">Save</a>`
    
    
         // i should be able to edit the title and body of a note when i click
         // on it and it should save when i click on the button.
    
         const noteId = event.target.dataset.id
         const editTitleInput = document.querySelector(`h1[data-id="${noteId}"]`)
         const editBodyInput = document.querySelector(`p[data-id="${noteId}"]`)
         const singleNote = document.querySelector("#note")
         const allNotes = document.querySelectorAll("li")
    
         noteDetail.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
           if (event.target.id === "save") {
             fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes/${noteId}`, {
               method: "PATCH",
               headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 'Accepts': 'application/json'
               },
               body: JSON.stringify({
                 title: editTitleInput.innerText,
                 body: editBodyInput.innerText
               })
             }).then(function(response) {
               return response.json()
             }).then(function(note) {
                    singleNote.innerText = editTitleInput.innerText
                })
              }
            })
          })
        }
      })
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="column is-one-quarter">
    <p class="menu-label" style="font-size:15px;">
      Notes <i id="create" class="fas fa-plus-circle has-text-grey-light hvr-grow" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 20px; height: 30px; font-size: 24px;"></i>
    </p>
      <ul class="menu-list">

      </ul>
 </div>

  <div class="column is-three-fifths">
    <div class="note-detail">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a form then? Can you show some more code? thanks :)

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for the delay. Im just back at my computer. I just want to ask a bit more. What data are u fetching with this request? multiple notes or just one? http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes/${event.target.dataset.id} .. Can you upload some of the HTML. I'd like to see the structure of the elements with class "note-detail" and "note-list" and "menu-item" etc. (and so I can test it.) Thanks

Comment: @Sarah Just one note that the user clicks on. Also, I updated the code with html.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm going to test it out now :) will get back to you in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems I can see.

When you are generating the HTML for the notes here:

```
notes.forEach(function(note) {
   noteList.innerHTML += `<li><a id="note" data-id=${note.id} class="menu-item">${note.title}</a></li>`
})
```

You are giving each note the same id (`id="note"`), and then later on, trying to set the innerText of element with `id="note"` but it will always get the first note with id of note. Your code is as follows:

```
const singleNote = document.querySelector('#note');
singleNote.innerText = editTitleInput.innerText;
```

So to solve this I suggest you concatenate the note-id to the element's id when generating the HTML (So that they each have a unique id) as follows:

```
notes.forEach(function(note) {
     noteList.innerHTML += `<li><a id="note${note.id}" data-id=${note.id} class="menu-item">${note.title}</a></li>`
})
```

And then get the appropriate element with the following query.

```
let singleNote = document.querySelector(`#note${noteId}`);
```

The second part of the problem I see is you are adding an eventListener to noteDetail,
inside the click event listener code of the noteList as follows:

```
noteList.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
...
  noteDetail.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    ....
  })
})
```

It means that every time noteList is clicked you are adding an event listener to noteDetail (which you had already done).
So when clicking on noteDetail, the code will execute several times instead of just once.

So to solve this I suggest you put the noteDetail click event listener outside the noteList click event listener.

Here's my full JS code. I've commented on the parts that i've changed. Hope it helps :)

```
  const noteContainer = document.querySelector(".column is-one-quarter")
  const noteList = document.querySelector(".menu-list")

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(notes) {
    //I changed the variable to "notes" instead of "note" as we're getting all notes here.
    notes.forEach(function(note) {
      //give a unique id to each note.
      noteList.innerHTML += `<li><a id="note${note.id}" data-id=${note.id} class="menu-item">${note.title}</a></li>`

    })
  })

  // display details of each note
  const noteDetail = document.querySelector(".note-detail");

  noteList.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className === "menu-item") {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes/${event.target.dataset.id}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(function(note) {
        noteDetail.innerHTML = `<h1 contenteditable="true" id="title" data-id=${note.id} class="subtitle is-2">${note.title}</h1><p contenteditable="true" id="body" data-id=${note.id} class="subtitle is-6">${note.body}</p><a id="save" class="button is-small">Save</a>`
      //I removed the noteDetail event listener from here
      })

    }
  })

  //Add the noteDetail event listener here (i.e outside of the noteList addEventListener code).
  noteDetail.addEventListener('click', function(event){ 

    if (event.target.id === "save") {
      //Now get the noteId of the current note being edited. 
      //We know this exists in both the data-id of the title and the body of noteDetail HTML 
      //so we retrieve it from one of these.
      //We could have also added a data-id to the save button of the noteDetail html. 
      //and then retrieved the noteId here with event.target.dataset.id
      let noteId = document.querySelector('#title').dataset.id;
      let editTitleInput = document.querySelector(`h1[data-id="${noteId}"]`);
      let editBodyInput = document.querySelector(`p[data-id="${noteId}"]`);
      //get the singleNote by it's unique id.
      let singleNote = document.querySelector(`#note${noteId}`);

      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/notes/${noteId}`, {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accepts': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            title: editTitleInput.innerText,
            body: editBodyInput.innerText
          })
      }).then(function(response) {
          return response.json()
      }).then(function(note) { 
          singleNote.innerText = editTitleInput.innerText;
      })
    }

  })
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184569/discussion-on-answer-by-sarah-i-want-the-title-of-my-note-that-i-clicked-on-to-c).